# Compile error when trying to use an Add button in Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I posted about this yesterday and have since made changes and attempted a few things to try and fix it and am still having trouble.

I'm working on a database for work and am getting a compile error when trying to add a record to a form.

It's essentially an inventory system, I have a table with the inventory of our warehouse and I'm trying to create a form that has a text box for every piece of information on a piece of equipment. So you go to the form, fill out each text box with the information and then there are 5 boxes to the side of the text boxes that you click to do different things. Below this there is a subform of the main inventory table.

There is an Add, Edit, Delete, Clear, and Close button. The Add button adds a record to this subform and consequently the main table with whatever information you type into the text boxes. To use the Edit box you click on a record in the subform and then click the Edit button and it will fill the text boxes with the information from the selected record, so that you can edit the information. At the same time, once you click Edit, it changes the label on the Add button to Update, so that once you have edited the data, you click Update and it will update the data in the subform and the main table. The other 3 buttons do what they're supposed to, you click a record and click delete to delete a record, click close to exit the form and click clear to clear any information that is filled in the text boxes.

The problem I'm having is that the Add/Update button isn't working - when I click it I get this error: Compile error: Method or data member not found. Every other button works perfectly fine and I have written and re written this code over twice now and can't figure out what's going on.

The weirdest part is that I basically copied this code over from another database that I coded that works exactly as intended and is super similar to this one. The only thing I even had to change when switching to this database was the names of the labels and table headers.

Can anyone help me out here?

Code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'when we click on Add button there are two options
    '1. for inserting new data
    '2. for updating selected data
    If Me.txtICN.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'add data to table after clicking the add button
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblInventory(ICN, manu, modelNum, serialNum, descr, dateRec, projectNum, dispo, flgDispo, dateRemoved, comments, ulNum, amcaNum)" & _
            "VALUES (" & Me.txtICN & ", '" & Me.txtManu & "', '" & Me.txtModel & "', '" & Me.txtSerial & "', '" & Me.txtDesc & "', '" & Me.txtDateRec & "', '" & Me.txtProjectNum & "','" & _
            Me.txtDispo & "', '" & Me.chkDispo & "', '" & Me.txtDateRemoved & "', '" & Me.txtComments & "', '" & Me.txtULNum & "', '" & Me.txtAMCANum & "')"

    Else
        'otherwise
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblInventory " & _
            " SET ICN =" & Me.txtICN & _
            ", manu ='" & Me.txtManu & "'" & _
            ", modelNum ='" & Me.txtModel & "'" & _
            ", serialNum ='" & Me.txtSerial & "'" & _
            ", descr ='" & Me.txtDescr & "'" & _
            ", dateRec ='" & Me.txtDateRec & "'" & _
            ", projectNum ='" & Me.txtProjectNum & "'" & _
            ", dispo ='" & Me.txtDispo & "'" & _
            ", flgDispo ='" & Me.chkDispo & "'" & _
            ", dateRemoved ='" & Me.txtDateRemoved & "'" & _
            ", comments ='" & Me.txtComments & "'" & _
            ", ulNum ='" & Me.txtULNum & "'" & _
            ", amcaNum ='" & Me.txtAMCANum & "'" & _
            " WHERE ICN =" & Me.txtICN.Tag
    End If

    'clear form after data has been added to the table
    cmdClear_Click
    'refresh data in list on form after form has been cleared
    frmInventorySub.Form.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()

    Me.txtICN = ""
    Me.txtManu = ""
    Me.txtModel = ""
    Me.txtSerial = ""
    Me.txtDesc = ""
    Me.txtDateRec = ""
    Me.txtProjectNum = ""
    Me.txtDispo = ""
    Me.chkDispo = ""
    Me.txtDateRemoved = ""
    Me.txtComments = ""
    Me.txtULNum = ""
    Me.txtAMCANum = ""

    'set focus to ICN number
    Me.txtICN.SetFocus
    'set edit button to enabled after data has been cleared from form
    Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    'change caption of button add to Add from Edit
    Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Add"
    'clear tag on txtICN
    Me.txtICN.Tag = ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    'delete record
    'check existingselected record
    If Not (Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'confirm delete
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?)", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            'delete now
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblInventory " & _
                "WHERE ICN=" & Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.Fields("ICN")
            'refresh data in list
            Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Requery
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
    'check to see if data is already in the form
    If Not (Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'pull data from selected record into the text boxes
        With Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset
            Me.txtICN = .Fields("ICN")
            Me.txtManu = .Fields("manu")
            Me.txtModel = .Fields("modelNum")
            Me.txtSerial = .Fields("serialNum")
            Me.txtDesc = .Fields("descr")
            Me.txtDateRec = .Fields("dateRec")
            Me.txtProjectNum = .Fields("projectNum")
            Me.txtDispo = .Fields("dispo")
            Me.chkDispo = .Fields("flgDispo")
            Me.txtDateRemoved = .Fields("dateRemoved")
            Me.txtComments = .Fields("comments")
            Me.txtULNum = .Fields("ulNum")
            Me.txtAMCANum = .Fields("amcaNum")
            'store ICN in tag of txtICN in case ICN is modified
            Me.txtICN.Tag = .Fields("ICN")
            'change caption of add button to Update
            Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Update"
            'disable edit button
            Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = False

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well, it's giving me the compile error at the cmdAdd_Click itself which is what is confusing me. Almost like it can't find the cmd or something I don't know.

Comment: **If Me.txtICN.Tag & "" = "" Then**
looks funny.   Why are you checking for a value in the tag.  If somehow your are editing the caption to Add or Update, use that caption value to switch between your insert and update functions.

Comment: (Sorry for deleting my original answer as it looked to be more than just one instance of the "tag" and it was rather ambiguous).   Also, watch out for the Insert if your table has autonumber because the insert looks like it's forcing a value in there.

Comment: My table does have auto number, but I tried it with and without auto number and ran into the same issue.

Comment: geeFlo could you explain what you're saying to me a bit more? How should I change that statement?

Comment: I'm not sure what that tag is looking for, and why it's the basis of your IF statement.   Perhaps you use the button you're clicking and do something like "IF me!cmdAdd.caption = 'Add' THEN"  (That is assuming your button's caption are somehow changing between "Add" and "Update" depending on the user's clicking of the EDIT button)

Comment: TAG itself is a hidden property in the field, so maybe you can explain why/how that's being used.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what is happening, but that change did not fix it either, it's still giving me the error at cmdAdd_Click which is really odd to me.

Comment: Yeah, you have to check out that funny IF statement.   It doesn't mean anything.  What is the '&' for and why's the = sign in quotes.  Either get rid of that junk and place a condition on a proper value that determines if the user wants an add or an update.

Comment: Do you have an easy suggestion on how I could do that? I'm very new to this and I had the IF statement in there like that on the recommendation from a work friend, but obviously it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see it now.   Your using the TAG property as an indicator if the record was edited or not.  i.e.  If it's a new record, then TAG = "", and if it's an existing record you replicate the ICN into the TAG.

If that's the case then change that IF statement to this:

```
If Me.txtICN.Tag = "" Then
```

Comment: Yeah that didn't do it either, I'm really stumped and frustrated on this one. Everytime I click add I get the error and it highlights Private Sub cmdAdd_Click() like it can't even find the method.

Comment: Try testing if the tag is null too.    > If nz(me.txtICN.Tag,"") = "" then <    Can't figure out how to hilite the code part, so just use the stuff between the arrows.